# Best Practice Analyzer for Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, best-practices

I tried searching around for a bit but nothing came up.
I know Microsoft makes BPA for Server 2008 R2 but was wondering if there is also a version for 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Server Manager, scroll to the bottom of the main page for each of your installed Roles. There is a section called "Resources and Support" that shows recommendations. This is the same place you will find 2008 R2's BPA which is installed as part of the OS now -- not a download, however it's slightly less feature-filled.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is only one for SBS 2008. I've never run  it on a regular Server 2008 install, it may not even let you set it up, but it may be worth a try.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=86a1aa32-9814-484e-bd43-3e42aec7f731&displaylang=en